# ipaddress swap causes both machines to be unreachable

Tags: networking, sles11

I got two virtual machines running on SLES11 SP3 in the same subnet for which I' d like to swap ip-addresses on the fly.
I tried the following script (of course with both different ip parameters) on both machines (login via ssh on both and than call it):

```
#! /bin/bash

sleep 20
ifconfig eth0 [[old_ip/new_ip]] netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Which caused both machines to be unreachable.

- What did I do wrong? Maybe yast plays a role?
- Any better idea how to perform the swap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your machines are probably unreachable because of ARP timeout issues.

You can trying sending out an unsolicited/gratuitous ARP rught after the IP swap with a tool like "arping", with something like `arping -U 10.0.0.1` (see also: [How to broadcast ARP update to all neighbors in Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/175803/how-to-broadcast-arp-update-to-all-neighbors-in-linux))